# How to start and kill a process (command shell ) inside a c program?

Tags: c, shell, command-line, arduino

I am using arduino to store some data from a thermocouple to the laptop ( OSX ). I want to use the stored data on a c program but i have some doubts.

i have this little example:

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>


int main (void)

{
    int a;
    a=fork();
    if(a==0)
    {
    system("cat /dev/cu.usbmodem1a21 - 9600 >> num.txt");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to redirect the serial ( arduino ) to some file, so i use `fork` to duplicate the process and run the command while the code is still under execution. However this is a dirty solution because i need to kill the process manually using the console. I want to know if there is a way to kill the process using c code inside the same program.

Thanks in advance.

ps: i have tried using getpid() and kill the process, but again i think is a dirty solution.

Comment: You may want to use one of `exec`s instead of `system`. `system` creates another shell and then another process for cat. In total you create 3 new processes here.

Comment: thanks your answer was very useful. I haves a lot os processes running at the same time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call getpid() to fetch pid. The function fork() returns child's pid in parent's process and 0 in child's process. So, you may directly send a SIGKILL to a child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        system("cat /dev/cu.usbmodem1a21 - 9600 >> num.txt");
    } else {
        /* ops */
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```